Intellij does not find types in node_modules/@firebase/firestore and wants to import from the compat packages instead
I'm using Intellij 2024.1.1 and when I opened my vue/typescript app it wants to import from my firebase/compat directory instead of the regular firebase types.
With no imports at all, npm run dev does not have any problems, so I think TS is configured properly, it's something with Intellij's configuration.
If I manually add this import Intellij likes it, but it's auto-importing the wrong packages:
import { QueryDocumentSnapshot, SnapshotOptions } from 'firebase/firestore'

How do I fix this?

tsconfig.json:
  "files": [],
  "references": [
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.node.json"
    },
    {
      "path": "./tsconfig.app.json"
    }
  ]
}

tsconfig.node.json:
  "extends": "@tsconfig/node20/tsconfig.json",
  "include": [
    "vite.config.*",
    "vitest.config.*",
    "cypress.config.*",
    "nightwatch.conf.*",
    "playwright.config.*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.node.tsbuildinfo",

    "module": "ESNext",
    "moduleResolution": "Bundler",
    "types": ["node"]
  }
}

tsconfig.app.json:
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.dom.json",
  "include": ["env.d.ts", "src/**/*", "src/**/*.vue"],
  "exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "tsBuildInfoFile": "./node_modules/.tmp/tsconfig.app.tsbuildinfo",

    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./src/*"]
    }
  }
}

package.json file is:
{
  "name": "pickup",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "run-p type-check \"build-only {@}\" --",
    "preview": "vite preview",
    "build-only": "vite build",
    "type-check": "vue-tsc --build --force",
    "lint": "eslint . --ext .vue,.js,.jsx,.cjs,.mjs,.ts,.tsx,.cts,.mts --fix --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "format": "prettier --write src/"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "firebase": "^10.12.0",
    "pinia": "^2.1.7",
    "primevue": "^3.52.0",
    "vue": "^3.4.21",
    "vue-router": "^4.3.0",
    "vuefire": "^3.1.23"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rushstack/eslint-patch": "^1.8.0",
    "@tsconfig/node20": "^20.1.4",
    "@types/node": "^20.12.5",
    "@vitejs/plugin-vue": "^5.0.4",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^9.0.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-typescript": "^13.0.0",
    "@vue/tsconfig": "^0.5.1",
    "eslint": "^8.57.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^9.23.0",
    "npm-run-all2": "^6.1.2",
    "prettier": "^3.2.5",
    "typescript": "~5.4.0",
    "vite": "^5.2.8",
    "vite-plugin-vue-devtools": "^7.0.25",
    "vue-tsc": "^2.0.11"
  }
}


Could you please share your package.json file so I can test this issue on my side?

@NataliaSoshenko - edited to add package.json - thanks!
